# Calculate a percentile using EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I'm trying to use either PERCENTILE.EXC, PERCENTILE.INC or PERCENTILE.

Looking at FormulaParserManager.GetImplementedFunctionNames() these are not implemented functions.

I wondered if I could set the formula and leave it to Excel to calculate. So far I've not got this to work and I get a #NAME? and "*The formula contains unrecognized text*". Merely clicking in the formula bar causes the formula to be calculated correctly.

Inspecting the internals of the Excel file I am creating (via EPPlus):

```
_xludf.PERCENTILE.EXC(B14:B113,0.95)
```

whereas in Excel I get:

```
_xlfn.PERCENTILE.EXC(A14:A113,0.95)
```

I think this is user defined function vs function. I've tried prefixing "_xlfn." to my formula string.

This is as far as I've got I think I either need to roll my own percentile calculation in code or manipulate the xml in the Excel file maybe.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I spend all afternoon stuck, post a question here and then immediately suss the answer...

Anyway in case anyone is interested:

```
var row95 = percentile95RowLookup[profileKey];
var percentileRange = sheet.Cells[row, i, row+ profileCollection.Profiles.Count-1, i];
sheet.Cells[row95, i].Formula = $"_xlfn.PERCENTILE.INC({percentileRange.Address},0.95)";
```

With the important proviso that workbook.CalcMode is not Manual.